# Need help flattening one mesh onto another

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I'm trying to make armor for skyrim I have a model of the body and the armor I'm trying to create. I can't simply merge the vertices as they have different vertices count and they have too many in general so I wouldn't be able to merge them all successfully. So I was thinking of turning to sculpting and seeing if its possible to flatten the armor mesh onto the body, someone please help.

This is the armor I am currently trying to edit:
[image]

This is the body:

[image]

Comment: pls screenshot to help understand your problem, thanks!

Comment: I'm currently not at my computer but when I get back to it I'll post the images

Comment: Solidify the body where you want the armor.

Comment: How do you do that? Solidify the body?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered i need to use the shrinkwrap modifier for a projects similar to this.